# How to exclude results in a query using a subquery as blacklist

Tags: sql, sqlite, hierarchical

I'm trying to query a database for text, use a (sub)query as a "blacklist". The twist: if any of the results from the main query have an identical beginning as any of the results from the subquery, they should be skipped.

A bit of background: I'm building a filebrowser, and using a table of foldernames to maintain the "favorited" state of entries. These favorites are intended to work in a cascading manner, i.e. any paths below a "explicitly" favorited path will be "implicitly" favorited.

Consider the following data:

| foldername | is_favorite | is_implicit_favorite |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo/ | 1 | 0 |
| foo/bar/ | 1 | 1 |
| foo/bar/baz/ | 0 | 1 |
| foo/bar2/ | 0 | 1 |
| foo/bar2/baz/ | 0 | 1 |
| foo2/bar/ | 0 | 0 |
| foo2/bar/baz/ | 0 | 0 |

Adding a favorite is easy: all folders below the given path will have their "implicit" state set. But I've found it hard to come up with a simple approach for the opposite - "unfavoriting" a folder. Because here, I want to the query to skip folders that should remain implicitly favorited (in the example above, unfavoriting "foo/" should skip folders below "foo/bar").

I've tried various solutions - the following approach comes close, but unfortunately only works with a *single* favorited subfolder:

```
SELECT DISTINCT folders.foldername FROM folders 
JOIN (
    SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
    WHERE folders.foldername LIKE 'foo/' || '%'
    AND folders.is_favorite = 1
) favs ON folders.foldername NOT LIKE favs.foldername || '%'
WHERE folders.foldername LIKE 'foo/' || '%'
```

It does what I want - unfavoriting "foo" should result in "foo/bar2/" and "foo/bar2/baz/" no longer being implicitly favorited, while "foo/bar/" (and its subfolders) remain unchanged:

| folders.foldername |
| --- |
| foo/ |
| foo/bar2/ |
| foo/bar2/baz/ |

View it online:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/8a04e/14/0

EDIT: thanks to Christians answer pointing me to the EXCEPT operator, I was able to come up with the following modified version that also works for multiple favorites.

```
SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
WHERE folders.foldername LIKE 'foo/' || '%'
EXCEPT 
SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
    WHERE folders.foldername <> 'foo/'
    AND folders.is_favorite = 1
) favs 
ON folders.foldername LIKE favs.foldername || '%'
```

I'm very happy that it's even possible at all to express this in pure SQL - I was briefly tempted to make it a hybrid SQL/node.js solution.

And of course, I'd happily accept any advice on possible optimizations!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient query, but it does the trick:

```
SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
WHERE folders.foldername LIKE 'foo/' || '%'
EXCEPT 
SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
    WHERE folders.foldername <> 'foo/'
    AND folders.is_favorite = 1
) favs 
ON folders.foldername LIKE favs.foldername || '%'
```

(Updated my original post)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PostgreSQL database, you can use this:

```
SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders WHERE folders.foldername LIKE 'foo/%'
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT folders.foldername FROM folders 
WHERE folders.foldername LIKE 'foo/%' AND folders.is_favorite = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do the trick - it's not enough to check if the "is_favorite" property is set, it has to match against all subfolders of the favorited folder(s). 
To verify this, I turned your query into a SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/38836/2/0

But interesting with the EXCEPT statement, I was not aware of that one (works in sqlite too)